# Piping an m3u8 link?

Tags: express, https, video-streaming, vercel

I'm trying to obfuscate the source of an m3u8 link by using piping through a vercel serverless function, something like this:

```
export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    await https.get('https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/img_bipbop_adv_example_fmp4/master.m3u8', function (response) {
        return response.pipe(res);
    });
}
```

I've been able to use the above to pipe through images however for m3u8s the video on the consumer never loads (ends up buffering the whole time).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You would need to proxy more than just the M3U8 playlist.  You also need to handle the proxying of all the segments.  Actually, you may end up needing to rewrite the URLs in the playlist too, if they aren't relative URLs.

Comment: @meds I would try... **(1)** Read the result into a buffer Array first. Then when load is complete, you can then send it to the video player for loading (as a Blob object?)...  Also **(2)** _"I've been able to use the above to pipe through images"_ Does it work if you try to load small MP4 files like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4)?